# Fullscreen using HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to fullscreen a div using JavaScript. Here is my HTML and JS:

```js
    var elem = document.getElementById('fullscreenThis');
    function openFullscreen() {
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
    }
    document.getElementById('fullscreen').addEventListener('click', openFullscreen);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <body>
    <div id="fullscreenThis">
        Here is some code I want to fullscreen
    </div>
    <button id="fullscreen">fullscreen</button>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried this in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: `var elem = document.getElementById('body');`: You have no element with the name of body. Maybe you meant `var elem = document.querySelector('body');`?

Comment: The area were it said "fullscreenThis" actually was body. I changed it a little bit before I posted it.

Comment: Take a good look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API. It's quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('fullscreenThis');

function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  }
}

document.getElementById('fullscreen').addEventListener('click', openFullscreen);
```

```html
<div id="fullscreenThis">
    Here is some code I want to fullscreen
</div>
<button id="fullscreen">fullscreen</button>
```

Hi Rayyan,

First I think you want to target `fullscreenThis` rather than `body`, then I want to direct your attention to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen

One useful snippet from this article is

> It's not guaranteed that the element will be put into full screen mode.

and also

> An element that you wish to place into full-screen mode has to meet a small number of simple requirements:
>
> - It must be one of the standard HTML elements or  or .
>   It is not a  element.
> - It must either be located within the top-level document or in an  which has the allowfullscreen attribute applied to it.
>
> Additionally, of course, the Feature Policy "fullscreen" permission must be granted.

I hope this helped you refactor your code in the right direction :)

Comment: I know. I changed it to fullscreenthis before I put it up, but forgot to change it in the js.

Answer (score 2):

By adding parentheses to the end of `openFullScreen` in the `addEventListener` call, you are calling that function. This means you are adding an event listener which is the return value of the `openFullScreen` function, which in this case is undefined.

To resolve this, simply remove the parentheses:

```
document.getElementById('fullscreen').addEventListener('click', openFullscreen);
```

You also need to call the requestFullScreen method on the element you want to make full screen, rather than the body element:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('fullscreenThis');

function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
document.getElementById('fullscreen').addEventListener('click', openFullscreen);
```

```html
<div id="fullscreenThis">
  Here is some code I want to fullscreen
</div>
<button id="fullscreen">fullscreen</button>
```

Note: The above snippet won't work correctly within SO because of sandboxing restrictions.

As mentioned by nthnchu, requesting full screen access must be as part of a user gesture such as a click. Just calling requestFullScreen in your code outside of a user gesture event listener will throw an error.

Comment: I also tried to make it full-screen automatically by simply adding openFullscreen() below were the function is declared. That has not worked for me, even after I removed the parentheses. What you said to do worked though.

Comment: That's because you were calling the requestFullsScreen method on the body, rather than the element you want to make full screen. I have edited my answer with a working snippet.

Comment: I also want to point out that just calling the function will not work at least in chrome. The browser will warn: Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.

Comment: Rayyan, Please could you accept the answer if it worked for you. @nthnchu that's a good point, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: It won't work since I don't have enough reputation. I have 11, and I need 15. :(